# A word or phrase to describe citizens of a country who are naturally inclined to defend the underdog

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase that can be used to define the citizens of a country who are naturally inclined to defend people from another country,race, religion etc simply because they are the underdog or they are being oppressed ?

**Example**

The citizens of Country A, comes to the rescue of Country B, because Country B is facing the threat of a military invasion from another country and Country B is ill equipped militarily to defend themselves from the invading country.

So, based on the above example what word or phrase can be used to define  the people of a Country A, who have sided with the underdog, Country B?

I looked up for a few words and came across the words *defender* , *altruistic* and *guardian*. However, I'm not sure if these words can be used to **define citizens of any country who will always side with the underdog or oppressed**.

Comment: That would be the *humane race*.

Comment: Calling Americans "a race of people" is a peculiar use of the word race in this day and age, likely to be confusing to most and objectionable to some.

Comment: I realise this may not be the place for a history lesson, but you might like to revisit your ideas about why the US became active in WWII. I doubt that simple altruism, or a desire to support the underdog, had much to do with it: https://owlcation.com/humanities/Reasons-for-American-Entry-Into-WWII

Comment: @Kiloran_speaking I'm just using the example to illustrate the point since the rules suggest that I need to provide an example. I'm not claiming that the example is historically correct.

Comment: @D_S Then perhaps you should have made up completely new examples instead of using real life examples.  It was definitely off-putting when I read the ones you provided (as an American, for the record).  It's not too late to create new examples either.

Comment: The "citizens" or "people"  of the USA did not come to aid of Kuwait; the sitting president made an executive order to protect the USA's "*national interests*" and this not out of love for underdogs.

Comment: Besides that, you're question is too broad. How are you defining 'underdog'? And do you really think any country would go to war to just support an underdog? France went to war to aid the American "patriots" (rebels) who pushed the colonies toward independence from Great Britain, but France did not do that because it loved the underdog. France lept at the chance to go to war against its traditional rival, whom they had just lost to in the 7-years War, aka French & Indian War.

Comment: I really think you should do away with all examples (real or hypothetical)  using the names of real countries. Not everybody is going to see Japan as an "underdog"  in any hypothetical conflict with North Korea, especially given recent headlines. Why not just use two fictional nation's names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Champion** is what you're looking for.

From the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/champion):

**champion** *noun [ C ] (SUPPORTER)*

> a person who enthusiastically supports, defends, or fights for a person, belief, right, or principle

For example:

> She has long been a champion of prisoners' rights/the disabled/free speech.

or another example from the *[New York  Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/04/02/world/asia/irene-fernandez-champion-of-oppressed-dies-at-67.html)*:

> Irene Fernandez, a champion of the oppressed in Malaysia whose indefatigable advocacy for better treatment of migrant workers prompted her government to denounce her as a traitor and human rights groups to shower her with awards, died on March 25 in Serdang, Malaysia.

I believe this also applies to a nation or a race - here's an (unfortunately negative) example for the United States (again from the  *[New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/06/25/opinion/americas-shameful-human-rights-record.html)*).

> [The] United States is abandoning its role as the global champion of human rights.